# How to achieve auto write and auto remove text from text input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the same output like in searchbox. please consider below url as an example:

https://www.reifendiscount.de/de/reifen/pkw-reifen.html

Here, single character is typing step by step automatically and after complete sentence is finished then each character is removed one by one from search box.

I need the same result for multiple sentences.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dir = 1;
var sentences = ["sent1","sent2","sent3"];
var sentIndex = 0;
function nextStep(){
    var input = document.getElementById("inputID");
    var val = input.getAttribute("placeholder") || "";
    val = sentences[sentIndex].substring(0,val.length+dir);
    if(val.length===sentences[sentIndex].length)dir=-1;
    if(val.length===0){
      dir=1;
      sentIndex = (sentIndex+1)%sentences.length;
    }
    input.setAttribute("placeholder",val);
}

window.setInterval(nextStep,100);
```

```html
<input id="inputID">
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. But this is only for single sentence. I need it for multiple sentences.

Comment: Thank you for giving me solution. This is the same what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```js
var text = "text_next_lua";
var isGrow = true;

var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  $("#inp").val(text.substr(0, $("#inp").val().length+(isGrow?1:-1)));
  if($("#inp").val() === text) {
    isGrow = false;
  }
    
  if(!$("#inp").val()) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }  
}, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp"/>
```